# jolt transformation to check if a key has null value

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Please help me in jolt transformation to check if a key has null value. The problem statement is mentioned as below.

For **input** where `TimeResolved` is **null**, `severity` will be ***as it is***:

```json
{
  "parameterid": "Testing rule for event ID_Testing 1.0",
  "severity": 2,
  "TimeResolved": null
}
```

**expected output**:

```json
{
  "parameterid": "Testing rule for event ID_Testing 1.0",
  "severity": 2,
  "TimeResolved": null
}
```

For **input** where `TimeResolved` is **not null**, `severity` will be changed to ***0***:

```json
{
  "parameterid": "Testing rule for event ID_Testing 1.0",
  "severity": 2,
  "TimeResolved": 123456
}
```

**expected output** is:

```json
{
  "parameterid": "Testing rule for event ID_Testing 1.0",
  "severity": 0,
  "TimeResolved": null
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to set `"TimeResolved"` to `null` in any case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***isNull*** and ***notNull*** functions within a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "NullCheck": ["=isNull(@(1,TimeResolved))", 0], // if TimeResolved is NOT NULL, then zero returns  
      "severity": "=notNull(@(1,NullCheck))", // stops silently if TimeResolved is NULL
      "TimeResolved": null // set to null in any case
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the "NullCheck" attribute
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "NullCheck": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your are a champ!